# implementing PayPal IPN in Django Application

Tags: django, paypal, paypal-ipn, django-2.0

I'm writing an application in `Django 2.0`

It is a multi membership application. I have to implement `PayPal` payment method and activate the membership based on payment received.

For this, I have created a button in PayPal with generates code as

**upgrade.html**

```
<form action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_top">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick">
<input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="<button-id>">
<input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
<img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

and **views.py** is

```
class Pricing(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'membership/pricing.html'


class Upgrade(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'membership/upgrade.html'


class PaymentSuccess(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'membership/payment-success.html'


class PaymentFailed(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'membership/payment-failed.html'


def paypal_ipn(request):
    # IPN response goes here
```

and **urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('pricing/', Pricing.as_view(), name='pricing'),
    path('upgrade/', Upgrade.as_view(), name='upgrade'),
    path('payment-success/', PaymentSuccess.as_view(), name='payment-success'),
    path('payment-failed/', PaymentFailed.as_view(), name='payment-failed'),
    path('paypal-ipn/', paypal_ipn, name='paypal-ipn'),
]
```

All is working fine as Payment is being made and user is redirected to the `payment-success` page.

But **How do I receive the payment confirmation so that I could process the membership and record the transaction data in the database?**

I have enabled `instant payment notification` from the settings in `paypal sandbox accoun` on url `https://example.com/paypal-ipn/`

*I do not want to use `django-paypal` plugin due to some limitations.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create your own IPN handling page to receive PayPal IPN message. IPN Sample code below.

https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples